# What two array indexes mean when placed one after another?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, while-loop

I'm just learning loops and can't get this part of the below script - what does `values [i][0]` mean here? (code found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27179623), described as a stopping condition). Is it the end and start of the array?

```
function getFirstEmptyRowByColumnArray() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var values = ss.getRange('A:A').getValues(); 
  var i = 0; 

  while (values[i] && values[i][0] !== "") { 
    i++; 
  } 

  return i + 1;
}
```

Comment: values would likely be an array of arrays.

Comment: The `getValues()` method returns a two dimensional array.  The inner arrays represent each row.  Each element an inner array represents a value in a spreadsheet cell.

Comment: @SandyGood Thank you. Am I right that applied to Google Sheets in the example code values[ i ] refers to a sheet's entire row,  and values[ i ] [ 0 ] refers to a cell (i for row number, 0 for column)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @SandyGood thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*values* is a more dimensional array. So the first index points to an array and the second index gives the element of that array. You can also imagine it as a matrix with rows and columns. The first index is the row and the second is the column.

If you want to know more about multi dimensional arrays in Javascript you can check out the answers to this question: [How can I create a two dimensional array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966225/how-can-i-create-a-two-dimensional-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Am I right that applied to Google Sheets in the example code values[ i ] refers to a sheet's entire row,  and values[ i ] [ 0 ] refers to a cell (i for row number, 0 for column)?

Comment: @VictorZhurbin Yes, the call ss.getRange( 'A:A' ).getValues() returns that data structure.

Comment: That was fast :) Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2):

Every array index operator (square brackets, aka computed member access aka [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)) accesses a single array element.  So if you see them in series, you are dealing with an array of arrays (or it will result in an error).  For example:

```
var arr = [
   [1, 2, 3], // inner array
   [4, 5, 6], // inner array
];
arr[0]         // [1, 2, 3]
arr[0][1]      // 2
arr[0][1][2]   // error: 2 is not an arry
```