# Getting last Row on Sheet with only hyperlinks/references

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet where there is a list of the other sheets in the spreadsheets with a link to them.
The link looks like that:

```
=HYPERLINK(\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/edit#gid="+sheetID+"\";"+"\""+name+"\")"
```

Note that the first sheet only contains these hyperlinks and a few references(=Test!B3 for example) to the other sheets and no direct Values.

When i try to get the last row with getLastRow() it always returns 0, disregarding the amount of rows actually filled with links/references.
The same occurs when i use the [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882104/faster-way-to-find-the-first-empty-row) proposed code:

```
function getFirstEmptyRow(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var row=0; row<values.length; row++) {
    if (!values[row].join("")) break;
  }
  return (row+1);
}
```

It also always returns 1. So i came to the conclusion that hyperlinks and references do not count as Cell Value. Is there any way to get the last row with references/hyperlinks in it, getting the last row of the sheet that is actually used?
The whole code of the function:

```
function restoreSheet(form)
{
    try
    {
        var name = form.pRestore;
        if (name != "")
        {
            var archive = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
            var sheet = archive.getSheetByName(name);
            var list = archive.getSheetByName('list');
            var values = list.getDataRange().getValues();
            var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID');
            var overview = destination.getSheetByName('cover sheet');
            for (var i = 0; i < list.getLastRow(); i++)
            {
                if (values[i][0] == name)
                {
                    var rowIndex = i + 1;
                }
                else if (i >= overview.getLastRow())
                {
                    return false;
                }

            }
            //erasing stuff on the archives
            sheet.copyTo(destination).setName(name);
            archive.deleteSheet(sheet);
            list.deleteRow(rowIndex);
            list.sort(1);
            // adding stuff to the overview
            var rowindex = getFirstEmptyRow(overview);
            var ssID = ss.getId(); //ID of the spreadsheet for link creation
            var oldSheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
            if (oldSheet != null)
            {
                var sheetID = oldSheet.getSheetId(); //ID of the sheet for link creation
            }
            else
            {
                Browser.msgBox(oldName + " was not found");
            }
            var link = "=HYPERLINK(\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssID + "/edit#gid=" + sheetID + "\";" + "\"" + name + "\")";
            overview.getRange(rowIndex + 1, 3).setValue(link); //Project Name (so that ppl who can only see the sheet can get to the right sheet
            overview.getRange(rowIndex + 1, 4).setValue("='" + name + "'!B3"); //Project Owner
            overview.getRange(rowIndex + 1, 5).setValue("='" + name + "'!H1"); //Group
            overview.getRange(rowIndex + 1, 6).setValue("='" + name + "'!N1"); //Tags
            overview.getRange(rowIndex + 1, 7).setValue("='" + name + "'!M11"); //Wanted
            overview.getRange(rowIndex + 1, 8).setValue("='" + name + "'!F1"); //Status  
        }
        else
        {
            Browser.msgBox("Not all required fields filled");
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        Browser.msgBox(e);
    }
}
/**
* Function to get the first completely empty row
*/
function getFirstEmptyRow(sheet) {
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var row=0; row<values.length; row++) {
    if (!values[row].join("")) break;
  }
  return (row+1);
}
```

Comment: Have these hyperlinks been made by the script or pasted manually?

Comment: The Hyperlinks have  been created by the script, as well as the references. But by a different function. There is also a function to rename a sheet. This function compares the hyperlink(getFormular works) and then creates a new one with the new sheets name. That works, just getting the last row does not.

Comment: I don't know the exact reason, to solve it, need all your code to try. You may use this: `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` before   `Logger.log(sheet.getLastRow());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
As can be seen in the code in the beginning, i chose the same variable name for 2 different sheet row indexes. That caused the script to take the wrong one. I feel pretty dumb for not seeing it :/.

Answer (score 0):

> [flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)
>
> Applies all pending Spreadsheet changes. Spreadsheet operations are
>   sometimes bundled together to improve performance, such as when doing
>   multiple calls to Range.getValue(). However, sometimes you may want to
>   make sure that all pending changes are made right away, for instance
>   to show users data as a script is executing.

`SpreadsheetApp.flush();` before `Logger.log(sheet.getLastRow());` can help

Comment: Ok. the solution did not work, gonna provide my code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the confusion, flush() seemed to solve it, but that was just a coincidence and me to happy to doublecheck.