# Google Apps Script - Find Last Empty Row of a Column in Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have currently a script like this: (Which will run every minute and fetch any values)

```
  // function 01
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 6).setValues(values);

  // function 02
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1, 10, 1, 6).setValues(values);
```

It finds the last row and set the values in next row. Both are in separate functions. But currently it outputs something like this.

**Current Output : NOT GOOD**

```
// function 1 output here       // function 2 output here
------------------------------------------------------------
|   A    |     B    |   C     ||         |         |        |
------------------------------------------------------------
|        |          |         ||   D     |    E    |   F    |
------------------------------------------------------------
|        |          |         ||   G     |    H    |   I    |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   J    |    K     |   L     ||         |         |        |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want that to be displayed like this:

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|   A    |     B    |   C     ||   D     |    E    |   F    |
------------------------------------------------------------
|   J    |     K    |    L    ||   G     |    H    |   I    |
------------------------------------------------------------
|        |          |         ||         |         |        |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Hope I'm clear.

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882104/faster-way-to-find-the-first-empty-row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below function, very slightly modified to pass the column from the solution Mogsdad supplied on Nov 27, 2014 for the New Sheets in response to the thread [Faster way to find the first empty row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882104/faster-way-to-find-the-first-empty-row)

```
// Don's array approach - checks first column only
// With added stopping condition & correct result.
// From answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9102463/1677912
// Added the passing of myColumn which needs to be a column range
// example use: var emptyRow = getFirstEmptyRowByColumnArray('B:B');
function getFirstEmptyRowByColumnArray(myColumn) {
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var column = spr.getRange(myColumn);
  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  return (ct+1);
}
```

It could, of course, be written instead to just pass the column and create the range if you like.