# Random slowness of Google Spreadsheet scripts

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

We’ve been working on the last moths to a scripts to manage a Google Spreadsheet.
The whole project worked flawlessly for moths, but in the last week randomly the whole script become extremely slow.
All the function call from spreadsheet data (getLastRow, getLastColum, getRange) take 10s to complete. In doesn’t matter it the range contains a single cell, or 100.

The script doesn’t throw any quota exception (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) , so I think that this can’t be the problem. The slowness hit the spreadsheet randomly each day, then a few hours later the problem seem to reduce than disappear, to come back again later.

We've made a new serie of test: we've created a copy of the spreadsheet with all data and script.
So we've got the same script, same data set, on the new spreadsheet everything works fine. On the old one the slowness is still present.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There is similar report on [Google Apps Script Issues Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list):

<strike>Issue [6102](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6102): getLastRow() sometimes requires extremely high runtime</strike>

[Issue 64931371](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64931371): function as openById, getLastRow very slow (5/10 seconds) intermittently

Star the issue and add a comment with the summary of your tests.