# Google Sheets API V4 - Find next empty row

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

What's the best potential way to find the next empty row using the Google Sheets API V4?
I've done some research and found some very insightful answers from [Omiod's post about the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882104/faster-way-to-find-the-first-empty-row?newreg=60b189b33cf9460faedf46a2f8150cf7), however presumably in V3 or potentially even V2.

Since V4's introduction, the API has undergone a seemingly difficulty-enhancing upgrade, and I can't seem to figure it out using the new libraries and their functions.

Any and all help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Sheetsv4 API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading) ignores empty rows. So there's no ad-hoc method to detect if the row is empty. What you can do is read the entire range and perform an if statement to see if a certain cell has value or not.

Comment: What do you think would be the best way to do this? Was hoping this wasn't the answer but reading the entire range of all rows seems rather slow.

Comment: let me see if i can share my snippet on how i handle 'empty cells'. it's more of a workaround than an ad-hoc function from sheets api