# Skip over previously entered data and add rows above a certain row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to move data from two sheets to one separate sheet. My code works provided the sheet is laid out as follows:[image]

However, the sheet must be laid out like this:
[image]

I need to insert data above the row containing `Amount Total` but below the first row containing the headers. I feel this may be possible by adding rows above the `Amount Total` using the script but my current code uses `getLastRow()` to skip over the existing data in exports sheet. This does not work when `Amount Total` is placed as shown in the 2nd image. How can I achieve this? My existing code is below:

```
function exportData() {

  var ards = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Newtownards");
  var bangor = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Bangor");
  var export = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Export");
  var lastRow = export.getLastRow();
  var nextCell = lastRow + 1;

  //get values for export
   var ardsRefValues = ards.getRange("B12:G12").getValues();
   var ardsAmountValues = ards.getRange("B13:G13").getValues();

   var bangorRefValues = bangor.getRange("B12:G12").getValues();
   var bangorAmountValues = bangor.getRange("B13:G13").getValues();

  for(var i = 0; i<=6; i++){

    var a = ardsRefValues.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);
    var b = ardsAmountValues.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);

    var c = bangorRefValues.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);
    var d = bangorAmountValues.join().split(',').filter(Boolean);


  }//close for loop

  //find length of the arrays
  var aLength = a.length - 1;
  var cLength = c.length - 1;

  //loop through ards data arrays
  for(i = 0; i<=aLength; i++){
     export.getRange(nextCell, 5).setValue(a[i]);
     export.getRange(nextCell, 4).setValue(b[i]);
     nextCell++
      }//close for loop

  //loop through bangor data arrays
  for(i = 0; i<=cLength; i++){
     export.getRange(nextCell, 5).setValue(c[i]);
     export.getRange(nextCell, 4).setValue(d[i]);
     nextCell++
      }//close for loop

  var data = new Array();
  var lastRow = export.getLastRow();
  var total = 0;

  for(var i = 2; i<=lastRow; i++){
    var range = export.getRange(i, 4);
    data = range.getValue();
    total += data;
  }
  export.getRange(2, 7).setValue(total);
}//close function
```

**Update:** Good news is that these sheets will be updated every week. So the amount Total must be added into the row just below the last row of data

Comment: If the header is always on the first row, you can use `var nextCell = 1;` instead of `var nextCell = lastRow + 1;`.

Comment: @Titus Thank you, I will try that

Comment: @Titus This works if I use `var nextCell = 2;` however, when I run the code again, it just writes over the existing data, rather than skipping to the next available row

Comment: I see, in that case, you can use something like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9102463/1552587) to find the first empty row.

Comment: @Titus Good news is that the export sheet will be updated every week, the total amount can be put in directly underneath the last row of data! I will update the code. Thank you for your help