# getting the difference between the last row of two columns in order to add values to the cells, making the columns equal in length

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a query gathering names from a master list and putting them onto a sheet.  As it adds and takes away names from that sheet I wanted to add and take away datavalidation drop down boxes that go along with the names.

So I came up with the idea of finding the last row of the A column and the last row of the C column, because C is where the drop down box is and A is their name.  And by getting the difference of these two columns and can determine not just the location but the magnitude of how much cells need to change.

A few things i found out was that Data validation lists aren't given with the first item, which is both good and bad.  So I had to make a setValue function that sets a name on the "PLACE" the drop down boxes go, because without it, the last row of Column C would be considered less, because Data validation drop down boxes count as "".

This is why I need the difference in the two columns, so I could Add "PLACE" to the cells that are Validation boxes without replaces every single cell in Column C with the word "PLACE"  Because it would happen every time the sheet was edited. I found some ways to find the last rows of individual columns I figured just columnA-ColumnC or so. Even made them in absolute.  But there is one number I wasn't allowed to have them for a range or else it ruins the whole system.  0.

```
function setValue(cellName, value) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(cellName).setValue(value);
}
function onChange(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var FirstEmptyA = getFirstEmptyRow('A:A');
    Logger.log(FirstEmptyA);
  var FirstEmptyC = getFirstEmptyRow('C:C');
    Logger.log(FirstEmptyC);
  var dif = Math.abs(FirstEmptyA - FirstEmptyC);
    Logger.log(dif);
  var rangeA = ss.getRange(2,3,FirstEmptyA -1)
  var rangedif =ss.getRange(FirstEmptyA+1,3,dif-1)
  var EmptyArow =ss.getRange(FirstEmptyA,3)
  var validationList = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['PLACE','MALL','BANK','SCHOOL'], true).build()
  if(FirstEmptyA - FirstEmptyC < 0){
        rangedif.clearDataValidations();
    rangedif.clearContent();
  }
 else if(FirstEmptyC - FirstEmptyA < 0) {
     rangeA.setDataValidation(validationList); 
        rangedif.setValue('PLACE');
  }
  else if (FirstEmptyC-FirstEmptyA = 0){
    EmptyArow.setDataValidation(validationList);
            setValue('C' + FirstEmptyC,'PLACE');
}
}
// From answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9102463/1677912
function getFirstEmptyRow(range) {
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var column = spr.getRange(range);
  var values = column.getValues();
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  return (ct);
}
```

I've been trying many different if else methods to no real help because i can't get a log whenever I use the function `onChange` in action.  if I run `onChange` in the script editor everything is running fine, but if I edit anything in the sheet, it gives back the good ol' `[]`
Things still happen, but the logs don't provide me with much info.  I think it has to do with the cell I'm editing isn't in column C.

Other than that, when I do get it to do things, the placement of "PLACE" or datavalidation is usually a bit off the mark.  Because I'm trying to compensate by adding or subtracting digits to make it not equal 0.  Any idea how to overcome this issue?

**EDIT 5/17/2019**
GOT IT!

```
function onChange(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var FirstEmptyA = getFirstEmptyRow('A:A');
    Logger.log(FirstEmptyA);
  var FirstEmptyC = getFirstEmptyRow('C:C');
    Logger.log(FirstEmptyC);
  var dif = Math.abs(FirstEmptyA - FirstEmptyC);
    Logger.log(dif);
  var EmptyArow =ss.getRange(FirstEmptyA ,3)
  var validationList = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['OASIS','LAT','CQ','MDR'], true).build()
  if(FirstEmptyA - FirstEmptyC < 0){
      var rangedif =ss.getRange(FirstEmptyA+1,3,dif)
        rangedif.clearDataValidations();
    rangedif.clearContent();
  }
 else if(FirstEmptyC - FirstEmptyA < 0) {
     var rangedif =ss.getRange(FirstEmptyC +1,3,dif)
     rangedif.setDataValidation(validationList); 
        rangedif.setValue('OASIS');
  }

}
function getFirstEmptyRow(range) {
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var column = spr.getRange(range);
  var values = column.getValues();
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  return (ct);
}
```

It was honestly just a matter of shifting the code around and adding numbers in certain areas.  Getting empty of C instead of A for the second if else function.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your `getFirstEmptyRow(range)` returns the row zero-indexed. But you use it to get empty A row in `var EmptyArow =ss.getRange(FirstEmptyA,3)` which would give you the row above the empty row. Try fixing it and let us know whether it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question check above.  Thanks though, Aung49.  I certainly double checked.  guess I just needed some sleep.

```
function onChange(e){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var FirstEmptyA = getFirstEmptyRow('A:A');
    Logger.log(FirstEmptyA);
  var FirstEmptyC = getFirstEmptyRow('C:C');
    Logger.log(FirstEmptyC);
  var dif = Math.abs(FirstEmptyA - FirstEmptyC);
    Logger.log(dif);
  var EmptyArow =ss.getRange(FirstEmptyA ,3)
  var validationList = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(['OASIS','LAT','CQ','MDR'], true).build()
  if(FirstEmptyA - FirstEmptyC < 0){
      var rangedif =ss.getRange(FirstEmptyA+1,3,dif)
        rangedif.clearDataValidations();
    rangedif.clearContent();
  }
 else if(FirstEmptyC - FirstEmptyA < 0) {
     var rangedif =ss.getRange(FirstEmptyC +1,3,dif)
     rangedif.setDataValidation(validationList); 
        rangedif.setValue('OASIS');
  }

}
function getFirstEmptyRow(range) {
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var column = spr.getRange(range);
  var values = column.getValues();
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  return (ct);
}
```