# How would I identify all blank cells in a column, and sync a separate tab to the entire row of data for each blank space in that column?

Tags: google-sheets

Sheets newbie here. I am working on a multi-tab sheet, where I'm trying to identify in real time all the blank cells in a column, and for each, grab its respective row, and put it into a separate tab. I don't need the entirety of the row, just a few columns out of the row. I'm not sure if this can be 
auto-populated in real time, but any help is greatly appreciated!

I tried using a query with an `ISBLANK` function on the column, but it was giving me parsing errors.

Comment: This is a pretty popular topic and a quick google revealed [Faster way to find the first empty row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6882104/1330560), and [Jump to next empty cell in specific column](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/121612/196152); but there are many, many more. As for on the fly, have you though about an `onEdit(e)` trigger - you just need to be sure that the cell deleted isn't going to be "re-filled" with some other data. @player0 is right, you do need to share your spreadsheet, and would you please edit your question to explain which columns are to be copied, to where, etc.

Comment: @Tedinoz I will add screencaps of my sheet and desired outcome. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Please don’t use screen caps. However you choose to do it, please provide shared access to an actual spreadsheet. This is much better for people who might assist you.