# Google Appscript: Place text in the first empty row of a specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to place text inside the first empty row of a specific column. I've tried following the link  [Faster way to find the first empty row in a Google Sheet column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882104/faster-way-to-find-the-first-empty-row-in-a-google-sheet-column)
 and I believe that instead of using `return` I should use something different as I want to place text inside that column instead of going to that column.

I tried the code to place text but I can only do that for a specific row and column

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var cell = sheet.getRange(1,3);
cell.setValue('hello');
```

How do I implement the above to the code below i.e. once it iterates finish, place text in the first empty row of column C

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var column = sheet.getRange('C:C');//specific column
var values = column.getValues();//get all data in that column 

var row = 0;
for (var row=0; row<values.length; row++) {
  if (!values[row].join("")) break;
}
return ('hello');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, when the for loop is finished, `row` is the 1st empty row number. This value can be used like `sheet.getRange(row + 1, 3).setValue('hello');`.
- When `C:C` is modified to `'C1:C' + sheet.getLastRow()`, the search range can be reduced.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var column = sheet.getRange('C1:C' + sheet.getLastRow());  // Modified
  var values = column.getValues();
  var row = 0;
  for (row=0; row<values.length; row++) {
    if (!values[row].join("")) break;
  }
  sheet.getRange(row + 1, 3).setValue('hello'); // Added
}
```

- When you run the modified script, `hello` is put to the column "C" of the 1st empty row in the active sheet.

#### Other pattern:

As other method, in your case, you might be able to use `getNextDataCell` as follows.

```
SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSheet()
  .getRange('C1')
  .getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN)
  .offset(1, 0)
  .setValue('hello');
```

#### Note:

- If you want to put the value to the last row of the column "C", please test the following script.

  ```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 3).setValue('hello');
  ```

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object))
- [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection)

Answer (score -2):

I think You don't need to check the row whether empty or not in spreadsheet before storing

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange(A:A).setValue("some_data");
```

by this using this you can simply store the value in first empty row in sheet. Please check and repond me after trying

Comment: This will set every value in A to "some_data". Also you need to have "" around the values inside of your getRange() function ie getRange("A:A")