# Script to copy data from set of cells to another set of cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm running a script which automatically generates values for the A and B columns, and then I want to copy the values generated through the E-I columns (columns C and D run formulas to print out values of E-I), and copy them into J-N (the initial values reload every time I open the sheet, so I'd like to just copy their value instead of using =E2 for example). This is what I'm working with so far:

```
function daily() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Instagram");
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "YYYY-MM-DD");
var aValues = sh.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var aLast = aValues.filter(String).length;

// Assuming A and B have same last row, no need for B
// If different, need to calculate separately
var bValues = sh.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
var bLast = bValues.filter(String).length;

// If A and B are the same, use setValues
sh.getRange(aLast + 1, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[date,'microdosehq']]);

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var balance = sheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues();
var nextRow = getFirstEmptyRow('J');
// Record current balance and timestamp at end of columns B & C
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 10, 1, 1).setValues([[balance]]);

}

// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/9102463/1677912
function getFirstEmptyRow(columnLetter) {
columnLetter = columnLetter || 'A';
var rangeA1 = columnLetter + ':' + columnLetter;
var spr = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var column = spr.getRange(rangeA1);
var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
var ct = 0;
while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
ct++;
}
return (ct+1); // +1 for compatibility with spreadsheet functions
}
```

But it's always returning the value of E1 into the next available J cell, and right now I'm not focused on all the columns, just column E. [I've added an image here to show what I'd like to accomplish at the end of the day.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8wPN.png)

Any extra support would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't see the relation between your image and your explanation since you image does not include column letters.  However I would recommend not using ranges like this `sheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues();` us this instead `sheet.getRange(1,5,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();` because the form will return nulls from lastRow() down to maxRows()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified your code due to having problems during testing.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Instagram");

function daily() {
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "YYYY-MM-DD");

  // Created a function that returns last row of column
  // Add 1 to get first row of column which does not have a value
  var aNext = getLastRow('A') + 1; 
  sh.getRange(aNext, 1, 1, 2).setValues([[date, 'microdosehq']]);

  // Assuming E-I columns have the same number of rows
  // Get last row of I which does have a value
  var iLast = getLastRow('I');
  // Excluded to get the header, if needed, change to E1
  var balance = sh.getRange("E2:I" + iLast).getDisplayValues();

  // Get first row of J which does not have a value
  var jNext = getLastRow('J') + 1;
  // Range of J-N starting from first blank J row
  var jNRange = "J" + jNext + ":N" + (jNext + balance.length - 1);

  // Copy values to J-N
  sh.getRange(jNRange).setValues(balance);
}

function getLastRow(column){
  var range = column + "1:" + column;
  var values = sh.getRange(range).getValues();
  return values.filter(String).length;
}
```

In short, the code above copies the rows under E-I, and are being appended under J-N, like what your snippet here shows:

```
var balance = sheet.getRange("E1:E").getValues();
var nextRow = getFirstEmptyRow('J');
// Although the line below doesn't append
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 10, 1, 1).setValues([[balance]]);
```

I removed everything that were unrelated to the question to show a clear answer, so please re-add them if needed.

Sample Data:

[image: sample data]

1st run:

[image: 1st run]

2nd run:

[image: 2nd run]

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. Feel free to clarify below if this was not the result you want.